# Why the result always is around 2.87

Tags: python, numpy, math, random

I have below code

```
result=0
loop_n=10000
for i in range(loop_n):
    result+=np.random.rand(3,4,10).std()
result=result/loop_n
print(result)
```

As I understand, if I run multi times, the result should be different because the result comes from random, but actually the result is always around 0.287

Is there some theory behind this?

Comment: btw: what is last line intended to express? it will only print in python console, otherwise you need `print()`. also include all the imports

Comment: I just try to understand of how python calculate the std

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: perhaps the better question should be "why the expect value is 0.287"

Comment: @RoMa `numpy` samples from a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)). The formula for standard deviation for a unifrom distribution is `sqrt((b-a)**2/12)` where `b` and `a` are the lower and upper bounds of the distribution. For `0` and `1`, this is `0.288`.

Answer (score 6):

It is just a proof that `np.random.rand` is a nice *uniform* random generator. You have 10000 observations of the standard deviation of a distribution following the same law. Standard deviation is the square root of variance, so or a uniform the *theoretic* (probabilistic) standard deviation is [`(max - min) / sqrt(12)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Moments). You have a fairly large sample size, so the *observed* estimator will be close to the theoretic standard deviation which is `1/sqrt(12)`, about 0.28867513459481287. But it nows becomes a mathematical question :-)

---

Assuming a uniform distribution on [0,1], the probabilistic (theoretic) mean E(X) is the integral of x on segment [0-1], which is 0.5. The variance is by definition E((X-E(X))<sup>2</sup>) which can be computed as the integral of x<sup>2</sup> on the segment [-0.5,0.5] and its square root gives the result written above.

Comment: Sorry to have written math in English, but SO does not support to easily write math symbols...

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Why so little variability?

That is the Law of large numbers. If you sample from a random variable often enough you expect to get a good estimate of the true mean.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

## 2. Why 0.287?

`rand` returns uniformly distributed numbers between 0 and 1 the true mean is therefore 1/2 and the true variance
is integral[-1/2..1/2] x^2 dx which you can check to be 1/12. The std is the square root of that `~0.289`.

## 3. Why not exactly sqrt(1/12) ~ 0.289?

But wait, that's a bit off. Why? Because `numpy` returns the sample var/std which is a biased estimator of the real thing, it systematically underestimates them. As you sample in relatively small batches of size `N=120` this makes a small but consistent difference. Once we plug in the correction N/(N-1) (sqrt of that for the std) we get a better match. You can try this in your code by passing keyword `ddof=1` to the `std`.

## 4. But with the correction the result seems a smidge too small?

That is correct. The correction factor `N/(N-1)` yields an unbiased estimator for the `var` but not for the `std`, basically because taking the mean and then the sqrt is not the same as taking the sqrt and then the mean.

You can check this by using `var` (still with argument `ddof=1`) instead of `std` and taking the sqrt after taking the mean:

```
loop_n=1000000
result=0
print_at = 1
for i in range(1, loop_n+1):
    result+=np.random.rand(3,4,10).var(ddof=1)
    if i == print_at:
        print(math.sqrt(result/i))
        print_at *= 10

print("...")
print(math.sqrt(1/12))
```

Sample run:

```
0.28103387158480164
0.2952158859220745
0.2902562660869275
0.28882685146952614
0.2887019908636715
0.2886783761564752
0.2886714244895549
...
0.28867513459481287
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look what you are doing:

- In each step, you have `np` generate 120 random values between 0 and 1 and get their standard deviation. It is always around 0.2887, sometimes more, sometimes less. Explanation see below.
- You add up all those standard deviations and divide them by their count. Essentially, you get their mean value.
- Because you have so many of them, they come closer and closer to the expected value of `0.2887`.

Explanation:

If you do `while 1: np.random.rand(3,4,10).std()` in a Python console, you see a lot of numbers emitted (until you press Ctrl-C), and they are sometimes `.266`, sometimes `.297` and so on.

But what do they mean? Well, the standard deviation is (very roughly spoken) the mean value of the distances of a collection of values from their mean value.

- If you take `[.5, .5, .5]`, the mean value is `.5`, the std is `0`.
- But with `[0, .5, 1]`, the mean value is `.5` as well, but the std is `.408248`.
- With `np.f64([.0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1]).std()`, you get `.316`.
- With `np.random.rand(300,300,300).std()`, you get about the same result as you do: always something around `.2887`. 
  Why the expected value is exactly `.2887` derives from the definition of the standard deviation. Essentially, it stems from the expected uniform distribution of what `np.random.rand()` produces.

Answer (score 0):

The numpy function `rand` draws a random number from the uniform distribution `[0, 1)`, which means that there is an equal probability to get any number between 0 and 1. Your code draws 120 random numbers from this distribution and computes an estimate of the standard deviation by using the formula

```
std = sqrt(mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2))
```

Your code then computes an average of the standard deviation estimate which should make the estimate converge to the theoretical value.

To compute the theoretical value we can use that `variance(x) = 1/12` for a random variable `X` in the uniform distribution. This implies that `std(x) = sqrt(1/12) = 0.2887`, which is close to the simulation result.